# Differential Drive robot non-holonomic constraint

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

For kinematic modeling of Differential Drive mobile robot besides three differential equations they usually put non-holonomic constraint like:

$\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{\phi}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} vcos(\phi) \\ vsin(\phi) \\ \omega \end{bmatrix}, \dot{x}sin(\phi)=\dot{y}cos(\phi)$.

Do we have to write $\dot{x}sin(\phi)=\dot{y}cos(\phi)$ as constraint, because it is obvious from differential equations if we divide $\dot{x}$ to $\dot{y}$. If yes what is the meaning of that?

Thanks

Comment: This mean that you have just two differential equations to solve $\dot x$ and $\dot \phi$ the solution for y(t) you get from the constraint equation

Comment: Thank you. But here we cannot say that our state space reduces to 2 because we need to know $y(0)$ for the full solution right?

Comment: $y=\int \dfrac{dx}{dt}\tan \left( \phi  \left( t\right) \right) dt+yo$

Comment: Ok, but I mean we cannot have two dimensional state space representation for our system right. Is it what we call non-holonomic?